# Проблема с индексами

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет у меня имеется 2 списка (один с именами, другой с различными местами). Суть в том что надо взять пару рандомных имен из первого списка и одно рандомное место из второго списка и вывести их вместе. Когда этот код выполняется вылезает indexerror

```
import random

chel = ["Буянов", "Валеева", "Волчугов", "Гусаров", "Димов", "Евстафьева", "Журенко", "Змиевская", "Иванова", "Кеян", "Латышев", "Леви", "Мушников", "Овсянникова", "Подставкин", "Снхчян", "Стаина", "Трофимов", "Халмвтов", "Шевкунова",]
 s_chel = len(chel)

mesta = ["Медпункт", "Лестница 1.1", "Лестница 1.2", "Столовка", "Холл", "Лестница2.1", "Лестница 2.2", "Лестница3.1", "Лестница 3.2", "Центр 2",]
s_mesta = len(mesta)

while True:
    part_1 = random.randint(0,s_chel-1)
    part_2 = random.randint(0,s_chel-1)
    part_3 = random.randint(0,s_mesta-1)
    if part_1 == part_2:
        print("\nНеполомка")
    elif part_1 != part_2:
        print("\n" + str(chel.pop(part_1)) + " " + str(chel.pop(part_2)) + " : " + str(mesta.pop(part_3)))
    elif s_chel and s_mesta == 0:
        break
print("Задача выполнена")
```

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду ```надо взять пару имен из первого списка и поставить на них одно место```?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А кто `s_chel` и `s_mesta` будет уменьшать после удаления элемента из массива?

Answer (score 1):

Метод `pop` возвращает элемент и УДАЛЯЕТ ЕГО ИЗ МАССИВА(!!!). Не знаю, хотели ли вы удалять его или просто не знали об этом, но массив у вас становиться короче, а ваши переменные с длиной вы не меняете, поэтому логично, что вы выходите за пределы массива.

В коде ниже я учла этот момент, плюс обратите внимание на строку `part_2 = random.randint(0, s_chel - 1)`: так как элемент по индексу part_2 вы будете удалять после того, как удалите элемент по индексу part_1, массив у вас уже будет на 1 елемент короче.

Далее из chel вы удалили 2 элемента, а из mesta 1 - уменьшаем переменные.

`s_chel < 2 or s_mesta == 0` - вы не сможете найти новые part_1, part_2 и part_3 без этого условия.

```
import random
chel = ["Буянов", "Валеева", "Волчугов", "Гусаров", "Димов", "Евстафьева", "Журенко", "Змиевская", "Иванова", "Кеян", "Латышев", "Леви", "Мушников", "Овсянникова", "Подставкин", "Снхчян", "Стаина", "Трофимов", "Халмвтов", "Шевкунова"]
s_chel = len(chel)-1

mesta = ["Медпункт", "Лестница 1.1", "Лестница 1.2", "Столовка", "Холл", "Лестница2.1", "Лестница 2.2", "Лестница3.1", "Лестница 3.2", "Центр 2"]
s_mesta = len(mesta)-1

while True:
  part_1 = random.randint(0, s_chel)
  part_2 = random.randint(0, s_chel - 1)
  part_3 = random.randint(0, s_mesta)
  if part_1 == part_2:
    print("\nНеполомка")
  elif part_1 != part_2:
    print("\n" + str(chel.pop(part_1)) + " " + str(chel.pop(part_2)) + " : " + str(mesta.pop(part_3)))
    s_chel -= 2
    s_mesta -= 1
  if s_chel < 2 or s_mesta == 0:
    break
print("Задача выполнена")
```

P.S. Ещё можно было бы обойтись без `s_chel` и `s_mesta` вообще.
Вы могли бы вместо этого каждый раз заново смотреть длину массива. А ещё равенство part_1 и part_2 вам бы ничем не помешало

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы не подключили библиотеку random, вам ошибка это и говорит. Напишите перед кодом import random

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).